# Partial View difficulty ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, session, razor

In the partial view I have to access `Session` variable `LoginInfo` which holds a `LoginInfo` object. I tried the following:

```
@LoginInfo info = @(LoginInfo)Session["LoginInfo"]
```

But it gives me compiler errors. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?\

Many things. The first thing you did wrong is the Razor syntax. It should be:

```
@{ LoginInfo info = (LoginInfo)Session["LoginInfo"]; }
```

But that's just the syntax. You have a far bigger problem. You have a design problem. You are violating the MVC pattern.

A view should not try to fetch any data. A view uses data that is passed to it from the controller action under the form of a view model.

So you define a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public LoginInfo LoginInfo { get; set; }
}
```

then you have a controller action:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel();
    model.LoginInfo = (LoginInfo)Session["LoginInfo"];
    return View(model);
}
```

then you have a strongly typed view in which you use the view model:

```
@model MyViewModel
<div>Hello @Model.LoginInfo.FirstName</div>
```

But in this case (given the name of the class `LoginInfo`) I suppose that you are trying to display some common widget on all views. That would be a great candidate for using the [Html.Action helper](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx).

So you define controller action that will fetch this information from some data source (Session in your case):

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult LoginInfo()
{
    var model = (LoginInfo)Session["LoginInfo"] ?? new LoginInfo();
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

and then you define a corresponding partial:

```
@model LoginInfo
<div>Hello @Model.FirstName @Model.LastName</div>
```

and finally in your _layout you can include this widget somewhere:

```
@Html.Action("LoginInfo", "SomeController")
```

Comment: I don't understand from ChildActionOnly and below can you explain how to  have the session view-able in the partial